# Why does command line windows FTP hang after password is entered?

Tags: windows, ftp

I use a script which includes a daily FTP job to copy remote files to our network. Sometimes FTP hangs, and I'd like to understand why.

Background: I use the Windows command line FTP to access a FTP site at my company. Most days, it works fine. Once in a while, FTP connects and prompts for user and password then hangs, either within my script or from the Windows command line. No errors are returned. If I FTP from the command line, I can interact with the FTP command line, for example showing "ls" if I type that, but it won't execute any commands, and I must use CTRL-C to exit though my next FTP attempt will still hang. If I FTP from within the script, the script hangs indefinitely. If our office manager physically restarts the FTP server, then FTP works again, but until then my script can't run and take care of other non-ftp tasks. I don't have access to the FTP server and there's no IT support onsite, so any insight on the following questions will help me work around this or to suggest a solution. I am stuck with the Windows command line and can't install other FTP clients.

1) What is going on when FTP hangs? Why are there no errors when FTP connects?

2) Is there a way to test whether FTP will hang prior to connecting? My script could then either skip the FTP job, or email the office manager to request a restart.

3) Is there a way to limit the time the FTP command is active? Presently it hangs indefinitely, but if it would time out, my script could proceed.

Comment: If restarting the FTP server fixes it, then the FTP server is the problem. Since you have no access to the FTP server, there' nothing we can offer you to help; the FTP server admin is going to have to be the one to figure it out.

Comment: OK, great. Is there a way to confirm the FTP server is having a problem, without using FTP and having it hang? If there is, my script can skip the daily FTP job but continue with the other tasks it takes care of.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by «It accepts commands such as "ls"»?  Do you mean simply that if you type the letters `L` and `S` on your keybouad, they appear on the screen?  Is this different from what happens if you type `quux`, `zaphod`, or `beeblebrox`?  (2) Can you break out by typing (Ctrl)+(C) or (Ctrl)+(Break)?  (3) If you break out, or go to a new window (or a different host), and try again, what happens?  (Does it suddenly, miraculously work, or does it still hang?)  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: It is probably possible to engineer some sort of timeout using the `sleep` command (if you have it), the `timeout` command, or `ping` (to simulate `sleep`), followed by a `taskkill`. I could maybe write such a thing, but I’d need to spend some time on it, and there are probably people here who could do it in their sleep, so I’ll just leave this as a suggestion.